# How to mock method before activity is created?

Tags: android, unit-testing, mocking, mockito, robolectric

I have an Activity

```
public class MyActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    public int i;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        i = getSomeInt();
    }

    protected int getSomeInt() {
        return 1; // here can be an api-request
    }

}
```

and i want to test it with **`robolectric 3.0`** and **`mockito`**.

But i need to mock `getSomeInt()` methiod.

```
@RunWith(RobolectricGradleTestRunner.class)
@Config(constants = BuildConfig.class)
public class MyActivityTest {

    private MyActivity mActivity;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {

        mActivity = spy(Robolectric.buildActivity(MyActivity.class).create().get());
        doReturn(2).when(mActivity).getSomeInt(); //but it is already after onCreate!

    }

    @Test
    public void testGetInt() {
        assertEquals(2, mActivity.i); //error
    }
}
```

Is it possible to use already mocked method by creating of activity?

**EDIT**

i have tried

```
@Before
public void setUp() {
    ActivityController<MyActivity> co = Robolectric.buildActivity(MyActivity.class);
    mActivity = spy(co.get());
    doReturn(2).when(mActivity).getSomeInt();
    co.create();
}
```

but i seems, that `onCreate` was not called by `mActivity`

`assertEquals(2, mActivity.i);` //gives the result:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected :2
Actual   :0
```

thanks Eugen for the consideration, it doesnt work, because `create` call on controller, that operates with activity that is not spied

Comment: Would you consider moving the `getsomeInt()` call to `onResume`?

Answer (score 1):

Mockito only mocks an object. But it cannot modify the activity reference of `ActivityController`.

So I try to isolate the function and pass it to activity before creating.

Four steps:

1. Isolate the functions as a member of a new class

   ```
   public class SomeInt{
       public int get() {
           return 1; // here can be an api-request
       }
   }
   ```
2. Use the functions by an object in `MyActivity`

   ```
   public class MyActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

       SomeInt someInt;

       @Override
       protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

           i = someInt.get();
       }
   }
   ```

   3. Make an API to set the object `someInt` in test

      - use `ShadowActivity` -- I recommanded this, separating the code and the test

        ```
        @Implements(MyActivity.class)
        public class ShadowMyActivity extends ShadowActivity
        {
            @RealObject
            private MyActivity myActivity;

            @Implementation
            public void setForMockito(SomeInt someint)
            {
                myActivity.someint = someint;
            }
        }
        ```
      - or let the object public

        `public SomeInt someInt;`
      - or make a public setter for the object in `MyActivity`
   4. Mock in test

      - If use `ShadowActivity`

        ```
        @Config(constants = BuildConfig.class shadows = ShadowMyActivity.class)
        Class TestMyActivity {

            @Before
            public void setUp()
            {
                SomeInt someIntMock = mock(SomeInt.class);

                ActivityController<MyActivity> co = Robolectric.buildActivity(MyActivity.class);

                mActivity.setForMockito(someIntMock);

                doReturn(2).when(someIntMock).get();

                co.create();

                // verify here or in tearDown
            }

            ...
        }
        ```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible. I tried to create the Activity in the test, spy it and then create a controller with that spy and I couldn't get that to work so I can't quite imagine how you could do it.

Now that said, it doesn't mean there is no solution to your underlying problem, just that spying the activity is not the way to do it. I would suggest that you ask a second question where you explain specifically what you're trying to achieve (e.g. mock the network component in tests) and you will probably get some alternative solutions that will get you there.